# Kubeflow returns a no such file or directory on container start

Tags: python-2.7, docker, dockerfile, kubeflow, kubeflow-pipelines

I'm currently trying to deploy a pipeline on Kubeflow, but everytime I start it, it returns:

> `This step is in Failed state with this message: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:345: starting container process caused "exec: \"python /usr/src/app/FeatureExtractor.py\": stat python /usr/src/app/FeatureExtractor.py: no such file or directory": unknown`

This is my pipeline: it currently fails on all fe-* components, which are required to run the other ones.

[image: Pipeline]

The Dockerfile of the image of said components is:

```
FROM python:2
COPY FeatureExtractor.py /usr/src/app/
COPY FE_freeze.pb /usr/src/app/
COPY DB /usr/src/app/
RUN pip install opencv-python==4.2.0.32
RUN pip install imutils
RUN pip install image
RUN pip install tensorflow==1.15
```

while the pipeline is created through this python function:

```
import kfp
from kfp import dsl

def feature_extractor(name, images, result):
    images = "--path_imgs={}".format(images)
    result = "--res_name={}".format(result)

    return dsl.ContainerOp(
        name=name,
        image='texdade/feature-extractor',
        command=['python /usr/src/app/FeatureExtractor.py'],
        arguments=['--pretrained_model="/usr/src/app/FE_freeze.pb"', images, result],
        file_outputs={
            'feature_vector':result,
        }
    )

def train_mv(name, primary, secondary, non_members, result):
    primary = "--members={}".format(primary)
    secondary = "--other_members={}".format(secondary)
    non_members = "--non_members={}".format(non_members)

    return dsl.ContainerOp(
        name=name,
        image='texdade/train-mv',
        command=['python /usr/src/app/Train-MV.py'],
        arguments=[primary, secondary, non_members, result],
        file_outputs={
            'model':result,
        }
    )

def test_mv(model_a, model_b, test_imgs):
    model_a = "--MV_A={}".format(model_a)
    model_b = "--MV_B={}".format(model_b)
    test_imgs = "--test_imgs={}".format(test_imgs)

    return dsl.ContainerOp(
        name="Test models",
        image="texdade/test-mv",
        command=['python /usr/src/app/Test-MV.py'],
        arguments=[model_a, model_b, test_imgs]
    )

@dsl.pipeline(
    name='First pipeline',
    description='FP'
)
def first_pipeline():
    FE_A = feature_extractor('FE members A', "/usr/src/app/DB/A/", "/usr/src/app/A.npz")
    FE_B = feature_extractor('FE members B', "/usr/src/app/DB/B/", "/usr/src/app/B.npz")
    FE_N = feature_extractor('FE Non members', "/usr/src/app/DB/N/", "/usr/src/app/N.npz")
    FE_Test = feature_extractor('FE Test dataset', "/usr/src/app/DB/Test", "/usr/src/app/Test.npz")
    train_a = train_mv("Train members A", FE_A.output, FE_B.output, FE_N.output, "/usr/src/app/A.pb")
    train_b = train_mv("Train members B", FE_B.output, FE_A.output, FE_N.output, "/usr/src/app/B.pb")
    test = test_mv(train_a.output, train_b.output, FE_Test.output)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    kfp.compiler.Compiler().compile(first_pipeline, __file__+ '.yaml')
```

The problem seems to the that FeatureExtractor.py can't be found on the container, which seems odd since launching the container manually (without Kubeflow) makes it execute.

Do you have any ideas on how to fix this?
Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: I'm not familiar with Kubeflow, but when you build docker image it should be tagged(default is latest). In you environment that image should be pushed to some registry. From that registry Kubeflow should pull the target image. What can happen is that correct image is not in registry or image is not pulled because image with the same name, tag exists in running environment.

Comment: Hi @robert, adding the ":latest" tag to the pulled image doesn't, unfortunately, work. The error remains :(

Comment: Dividing the command issued to each container into command=['python', 'path/to/script.py'] now returns error code 132, which isn't listed in the Kubeflow's documentation

Comment: I've had the same issue before, and I'm not sure this will work, but try removing the `command=` argument and instead include the path in the arguments, so that you change `arguments=['--pretrained_model="/usr/src/app/FE_freeze.pb"', images, result]` to `arguments=["/usr/src/app/FeatureExtractor.py",] + ['--pretrained_model="/usr/src/app/FE_freeze.pb"', images, result]`.

Comment: @Marcus Thank you but, unfortunately, every container still crashes with error code 132. If the error is linked to the Docker container, it means that the CPU architecture is too old. This isn't the case though, since running the container manually on the same machine returns the desired output with no error codes.

Comment: @texdade Thats unfortunate. I'm sorry that didn't work, and I'm trying to figure out why it does not recognize the file. Another thing to try could be to add an `ENTRYPOINT` to the end of your `Dockerfile`, as such: `ENTRYPOINT ["bash", "/usr/src/app/FeatureExtractor.py"]`. Or, if you include the path in the arguments as I suggested earlier, you might have to set the entry-point as `ENTRYPOINT ["python"]`.

Comment: Turns out it isn't a problem with my container/pipeline. I installed Minikf locally and my pipeline works, so I guess that the error code 132 is caused by the cluster in which Kubeflow is running...